# How to find the length of particular type within object using javascript?

Tags: javascript

i have object like below,

**Example 1**

```
input = {
    item_type: {
        id: ‘1’,
        name: ‘name1’,
    },
    children: [
        {
            type_1:  {
                id: ‘12’,
            },
            type: 'item1-type',
        },
        {
            children: [
                {
                    id: '1',
                    type: 'item2',
                },
                {
                    id: '2',
                    type:'item2',
                },
                {
                    id:'3',
                    type: 'item2',
                },
            ] 
            
            type: 'item2-type',
        },
        {
            children: [
                {
                    id: '4',
                    type: 'item2',
                },
                {
                    id: '5',
                    type:'item2',
                },
                {
                    id:'6',
                    type: 'item2',
                },
            ] 
            
            type: 'item2-type',
        },
    ]
}
```

now i want to find the count of "item2" type within children array within children array again.

note that the outer children array can be empty array and the children array within children array may not be present. so the input can be of types like below

```
input = {
    item_type: {
        id: ‘1’,
        name: ‘name1’,
    },
    children: [] //empty children array
}


input = {
    item_type: {
        id: ‘1’,
        name: ‘name1’,
    },
    children: 
        [ //no children array within
            {
                type_1:  {
                    id: ‘12’,
                },
                type: “item1-type”,
            },
        ]
    }
```

how can i find the count of type: "item2" within children array considering example1 input.

so the expected count is 6.

could someone help me with this. thanks. new to programming.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation (first code block) and the quotes into regular `'` and `"` quotes instead of those "special" things that will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Please check your question again. There are still invalid quotes and a misplaced `}`

Comment: thanks updated. invalid quotes i dont see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const findAllChildrenOfType = (obj, type) => {
    let count = 0;
    if (obj.type === type) count++;
    if (obj.children) {
        obj.children.forEach(child => {
            const childCount = findAllChildrenOfType(child, type);
            count += childCount;
        })
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(findAllChildrenOfType(input, "item2"))
```

Comment: thanks but the count is 0 always

Comment: it works on the example you provided